# Rewind of Players death in Unreal engine

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint, unreal-gameplay-ability-system

Can anybody suggest me how to make the Gears of war style like death? i.e, when players dies they show the rewind of how the player dies.

Comment: Unreal has a built in replay system. ( It will only play back things that are network replicated )

Answer (score 1):

Unreal has a very handy tool called Replay System that allows exactly this. You can check the official documentation [here](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Engine/Replay/index.html).

Though Multiplayer is not technically required, your game must support replication. This system supports Streamers who want to be able to use those replays to generate content, but you can stop the recording when the player dies, use the last 10 seconds (for example) and then discard it.

The commands you're looking for are `UGameInstance::StartRecordingReplay`, `UGameInstance::StopRecordingReplay` and `UGameInstance::PlayReplay`.

Basicly, you're doing some Client-Side demo recording.

Please let us know how it goes!